# returning stack of even integers but stack is empty

Tags: java, stack

i am tying to return a new stack with the even integers from an original stack in thier original order but my junit test keeps saying my stack is empty and does not contain the contain the correct values. could someone look at my code an explain what i am doing wrong? i cannot   use static  variables,  arrays  or  Java    collections.

*my code*

```
public class StackExample {
public static Stack<Integer> getEvenNumbers(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    Stack<Integer> a = stack;
    Stack<Integer> c = new Stack<Integer>();
    System.out.println(length(stack));
    if(length(stack)==1)
    {
        return stack;
    }
    while (!(a.isEmpty())) {
        int num = a.pop();
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            c.push(num);
        } else {

        }
    }
    System.out.println(c.isEmpty());
    return c;
}

public static int length(Stack<Integer> a) {
    int length = 0;
    while (!(a.isEmpty())) {
        a.pop();
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}
}
```

*provided stack class*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Stack<T> {
private List<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();

public void push(T value) {
    array.add( value );
}
public T pop() {
    int last = array.size() - 1;
    return array.remove( last );
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return array.isEmpty();
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return array.toString();
}
}
```

*my junit tests*

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import org.junit.Test;

public class StackExampleTest {
private class StackTest extends Stack<Integer> {
    public StackTest(int[] values) {
        for (int i = values.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
            push( values[ i ] );
        }
    }
}
@Test
public void testReflection() {
    Class<?> iClass  = StackExample.class;
    for (Field field : iClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (!field.isSynthetic()) {
            fail( "class should not have any fields" );
        }
    }
}
@Test
public void testEmpty() {
    int[]          input  = new int[]{ };
    Stack<Integer> stack  = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    assertTrue( "result should be empty", result.isEmpty() );
    assertTrue( "stack should be empty",  stack .isEmpty() );
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack != result );
}
@Test
public void test1Odd() {
    int[]          input   = new int[]{ 5 };
    Stack<Integer> stack   = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result  = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    assertTrue( "result should be empty", result.isEmpty() );

    for (int expected : input) {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"stack\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = stack.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack != result );
}
@Test
public void test1Even() {
    int[]          input   = new int[]{ 4 };
    Stack<Integer> stack   = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result  = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    for (int expected : new int[]{ 4 }) {
        if (result.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"result\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = result.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    for (int expected : input) {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"stack\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = stack.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack != result );
}
@Test
public void testNoneEven() {
    int[]          input   = new int[]{ 9, 77, 3, 5, 11 };
    Stack<Integer> stack   = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result  = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    assertTrue( "result should be empty", result.isEmpty() );

    for (int expected : input) {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"stack\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = stack.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack != result );
}
@Test
public void testSomeEven() {
    int[]          input   = new int[]{ 44, 77, 8, 3, 5, 12 };
    Stack<Integer> stack   = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result  = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    for (int expected : new int[]{ 44, 8, 12 }) {
        if (result.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"result\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = result.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    for (int expected : input) {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"stack\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = stack.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack != result );
}
@Test
public void testAllEven() {
    int[]          input   = new int[]{ 12, 22, 6, 14, 12 };
    Stack<Integer> stack   = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result  = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    for (int expected : input) {
        if (result.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"result\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = result.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    for (int expected : input) {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"stack\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = stack.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack != result );
}
 }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in an IDE debugger?  In general, posting a wall of code saying "Please debug this" is not considered appropriate. You should debug it, narrow down the problem to a _very_ simple testcase that demonstrates what you don't understand, and ask a specific question.

Comment: Could you modify your provided Stack class? I.e add a method size that returns the `size()` of the list.

Comment: i am not allowed to modify stack to a size()

Answer (score 2):

Your length function removes (pops) all elements from the stack.

Note that assigning an object reference to another variable like

```
Stack<Integer> a = c
```

does not copy the object - only a reference to the object.

Comment: Beat me to it, to fix this, add a size() method to the Stack class, although the size of the stack really shouldn't matter for what is being done as far as I can tell..

Comment: @turbo, the `Stack` class provided to the OP (I assume this is a school exercise) is not `java.util.Stack`, and it does not have a `size` method.

Comment: The input stack is also destroyed (cleared) while copying the even elements.

Comment: @BrianS I just noticed that, but it's easy enough to add in a method that returns `array.size()`.  Or, create a copy of the stack before checking length by popping.

Comment: @turbo, I suspect the OP is not permitted to modify the definition of `Stack`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original code (apart from the accident with length) also destroys the original stack and copies in reverse order.

```
Stack<Integer> copyEven( Stack<Integer> orig ){
    Stack<Integer> copy = new Stack<Integer>();
    doCopy( orig, copy );
    return copy;
}

void doCopy( Stack<Integer> orig, Stack<Integer> copy ){
    if( orig.isEmpty() ) return;
    Integer curr = orig.pop();
    doCopy( orig, copy );
    if( curr % 2 == 0 ) copy.push( curr );
    orig.push( curr );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `length()` method is counting the elements by popping all of them off the stack. So when it returns, no matter what the size of the stack *used* to be, the stack is now empty.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
if(length(stack)==1)
    {
        return stack;
    }
```

in `getEvenNumbers` is not necessary for anything, but returns if the input stack has one entry without doing anything

Answer (score 0):

Your `length` method is clearing your stack. Try changing it to something like this:

```
public static int length(Stack<Integer> a)
{
    Stack<Integer> store = new Stack<Integer>();
    int length = 0;
    while (!(a.isEmpty()))
    {
        store.push(a.pop());
        length++;
    }
    while (!(store.isEmpty()))
    {
        a.push(store.pop());
    }
    return length;
}
```

While it still clears your stack, it saves the values and puts them *back* onto your original stack before returning from `length`.